# Interpolating rotation around an axis - quaternions and slerp vs linear interpolation of angles

Tags: quaternions

Im making a simple 3d game where Ive got some boats colliding and changing directions to avoid eachother.

Part of the collision handling is built around bouncing and then diverting the heading direction slightly (boat A hit boat B, A bounces back then rotates say 10 degrees to the left and resumes movement)

So far, Ive just updated the heading direction, which looks a bit abrupt. I intend to interpolate from the old heading to the new one. It is very simple, the heading is always just an angle around one axis. So basically its going from say 90 degs to 110 degs.

Im aware of quaternions and slerp, which would give me a constant velocity (my rotation should be silky smooth). But I just end up feeling like its using a sledge hammer to kill a fly. What is really the consequence of just doing a regular vanilla linear interpolation from 90 to 110 for the rotation angle? Will it even be visually noticeable that I have used quaternions instead of the much simpler and much cheaper linear interpolation of angle values? I have no special important "key frames" that need to be hit - there is no "animational data" at all, the 3d models are static.

So if someone could shed some light of what potential problems I could run into if I just interpolate the rotation degrees instead of using slerp, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks
/Jim

Comment: Linear interpolation would work fine but probably look odd to humans. Animation with easing gives a more natural experience.

Comment: Linear interpolation of quaternions will look OK. Interpolating euler angels will look weird.

Also , in your case , best choice is STERP
http://allenchou.net/2018/05/game-math-swing-twist-interpolation-sterp/

Comment: I tried it out yesterday and visually it looks fine. It might be due to the fact that this is a very specific case of rotation. I rotate the boat around its own center point, simply going between different euler angles looks fine? I looked at the examples and at allenchou.net and that example dosent spin the object around its center point. If i was rotating the whole boat around say an island, Im sure this would look weird. Is my thinking correct or am I missing something?